# Symbolic Integration of Special Functions

Tags: symbolic, polynomials, special-functions

Sorry in advance if this formatting comes out strange, this is my first question! I can't find a way to integrate, e.g., a function of the Hermite polynomials for general (still integer) order. For example,

```
Integrate[E^-x^2 HermiteH[m,x] x HermiteH[n,x ], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
    Assumptions->{m \[Element] Integers, n \[Element] Integers, m >= 0, n >= 0]
```

will not calculate. But if I give specific m and n,

```
Integrate[E^-x^2 HermiteH[m,x] x HermiteH[n,x ]/.{m->2,n->1}, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

the answer comes right out. I know there is a general rule for certain classes of these integrals, and have often come across situations where I end up having to do them by hand.

Does anyone know how to make Mathematica recognize/do these integrals? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I ask for `HermiteH[m, x]` it does not return a general form. But if I ask for `HermiteH[2, x]` it does. This might be the place to look.

Comment: Because when you give numbers, you are now integrating polynomials with known length and terms. Mathematica can integrate combinations of polynomials much easier. When you do not specify $m,n$ values, Mathematica has to use the formal definition of $H(n)$ and it can't expand it to an actual polynomial. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitePolynomial.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In cases like this, a little help to Mathematica can often go a long way.  You can notice that for these functions, the integral is zero unless `Abs[n-m]==1`.  So you only need to generate a 1D table:

```
 tab=Table[Integrate[E^-x^2 HermiteH[n-1,x] x HermiteH[n,x],{x,-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}],{n,1,5}];
```

and this result can be fed to `FindSequenceFunction`

```
 FindSequenceFunction[tab, n]
```

which returns:

```
 2^(-1 + n) Sqrt[\[Pi]] Pochhammer[1, n]
```

Comment: Maybe worth adding: if you apply `FunctionExpand` to this, you can also get rid of the `Pochhammer` symbol.